# how to show objects of nsarray on lable on tableview?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, nsarray

i have an `NSArray` of friends list on `viewdidload` , then i have a customized table view 
each cell consists a `Lable`, i want to show array elements in `Lable` on table view cell .

my code as

```
tableList1 = [[NSArray 

alloc]initWithObjects:@"Harendra",@"Satyendra",@"Jitendra",@"Sandeep",@"Dick",@"nihyan",@"alex

",@"Gorav",nil];
```

and

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


    }


//         ********   LableView    *******


UILabel* cellLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200,12, 141, 111)];
cellLabel.textColor=[UIColor greenColor];
cellLabel.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18];
//cell.textLabel.text = [callDetailArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text =[tableList1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
//  cellLabel.text =[NSArray arrayWithArray:tableList];
cellLabel.text = @"Lorem Ipsum";
cellLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cellLabel.opaque = NO;

[cell.contentView addSubview:cellLabel];



 NSLog(@" arr count in Friends list   %i",tableList1.count);
```

Comment: what's your problem in this code ?

Comment: i have an NSArray of friends list on viewdidload , then i have a customized table view each cell consists a Lable, i want to show array elements in Lable on table view cell .

so how can i do this ?? pls suggest me

Comment: i want to show array elements in Lable on table view cell , pls note i want to show on lable not on cells

Comment: what you want to print??full list of object or just one element?

Comment: please clear your question..u keep on saying same thing

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use this code

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

//********   LableView    *******

UILabel* cellLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,12, 141, 111)];
cellLabel.textColor=[UIColor greenColor];
cellLabel.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18];
cellLabel.text = [tableList1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cellLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cellLabel.opaque = NO;

[cell.contentView addSubview:cellLabel];
```

OR
check this two method you added in your code.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [tableList1 count];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 50;
}
```

I hope this code useful for you.

Comment: its working and don't shows any error .

Comment: - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 50;
}

in this place , i want to add a button dynamically to increase the hight of cell , so when user click upon that button it should be increse the hight of cell and then click again to resize the hight .

Thanks in Advance

Comment: @PratapManishBhadoria check this link for create custom button http://rahulvirja.blogspot.in/2012/05/how-to-create-custom-button-in-iphone.html

Comment: @PratapManishBhadoria for increase height create global int variable and increase that value and reload your table.

Answer (score -1):

Change `tableList1` to be `instance variable`

and

```
cell.textLabel.text =[self.tableList1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

or

```
cell.textLabel.text =[_tableList1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: he needs a add label in tablecell. not a only displa y array element in cell.